# How can I get Days and Months from YYYY-mm Format?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have many `varchar` YYYY-mm values in my table :

[image]

But now I need days in Month from this.

> I need the result: 2018-04 -> 30 Days

So how I can achieve this?

I thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `eomonth()`:

```
select day(eomonth(convert(date, yyyymm + '-01')))
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=4be2dbb3aa77fd7d0ef478bb414c6657) is a db<>fiddle for doubters.

Comment: I doubt whether an actual human being could have answered so quickly.  Admit it, you're a bot!

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen . . . The most important class I took in High School was touch typing.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Thank goodness I'm not alone on this.  I have another theory, but it requires a DNA test an perhaps a full body MRI scan

Comment: @Gordon Linoff: Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Gordon's spot-on answer, here is another way to compute the number of days in the month:

```
SELECT
    DATEDIFF(day,
             TRY_CONVERT(datetime, date+'01'),
             DATEADD(month, 1, TRY_CONVERT(datetime, date+'01')))
FROM yourTable;
```

### Demo

Actually, if you have a long term need for the number of days in each calendar month over some range, you might want to just create a calendar table with this fixed table.  Then, you may join to it whenever you need it.

Answer (score 0):

The eomonth() function does the job :)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).